# Webview loading using viewmodel

Tags: android, mvvm, android-webview, viewmodel

I was using extends Activity and onCreate() earlier for loading any webview define in xml layout.
E.g.

```
public void onCreate(){
WebView webview = findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
webview.loadUrl("url");
---
```

But now, we've to move all this logic to ViewModel. I don't have any idea of doing, could you please someone explain about the handling? 
I've gone through several blogs, but didn't see any such use of doing.

Comment: `"But now, we've to move all this logic to ViewModel."` you have to move it `ViewModel`? why? you should leave it where it is now (activity / fragment)

Comment: Product decide to implement MVVM structure now.

Comment: see [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel) docs: *"ViewModel's only responsibility is to manage the data for the UI. It **should never** access your view hierarchy or hold a reference back to the Activity or the Fragment."*

Comment: @pskink, I means to say product team. Let me go through https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel.

Comment: so see my comment above - note: **should never**